# What determines the wavelength for an electron slit experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, visible-light, double-slit-experiment, wave-particle-duality

Say we have a double slit experiment. Besides the slit width, separation and distance from the detection screen, the color of light determines the fringe pattern spacing's. So red and blue have different patterns. Now if you take the same exact double slit experiment and fire electrons what determines the wavelength or pattern?

Comment: Bill, the velocity of the electrons as well as the electric potential of the slit influence the intensity distribution on the observers screen. Historical facts about electron deflection at edges see my elaboration https://www.academia.edu/27983554/Deflection_of_electron_beams_at_edges

Comment: @HolgerFiedler thanks I assumed it had something to do with that but wasn't sure. So really there are a lot of variables? Depending on the Electron speed The emitted photons could be any frequency? Could the frequency be so high that the pattern is hard to see? Could multiple electron impacts vary to the point that frequencies mixed and destroyed the pattern? Is there an an article or paper on this particular subject?

Comment: Why do you think that a moving electron has to emit photons? BTW the impact on the observers screen is really an electron and not from photons.

Comment: I don't think moving electrons emit photons. I only think accelerated electrons do. Either when they bump the slit edges or impact the screen. I realize the impacts are made by electrons but I'm suggesting they're being guided by the unseen photon pattern. That's the reason for my original question what determines the frequency that also determines the pattern?

Answer (score 1):

> *"the color of light determines the fringe pattern spacing"*

Not the color, the *wavelength*. Yes, these ideas are coupled, but if you perform the experiment in a medium of non-trivial index of refraction, the fringes shift.<sup>1</sup>

And that tells you the property to use for particle version of the experiment: the de Broglie wavelength.

(You can also deduce this from how the interference develops: the two path from slit to screen cover different *distances*.)

---

<sup>1</sup> This is roughly how gas indexes of refraction are measured, though they use a more powerful interferometer than a simple pair of slits.

Comment: Yes I realize it's not the color but I would also say it's more the frequency. So ultimately  it comes down to slit width, slit separation, number of slits and and the wavelength or frequency. So if The experiment is set and we fire electrons at it what determines the wavelength or frequency?

Comment: No, it is **not** the frequency. It *is* the wavelength. The frequency doesn't change in a material medium and the wavelength does. Putting the experiment in a material medium shifts the fringes. It is very easy to get the idea that the two notions are interchangable (coupled as they are by the speed of light), but in some cases it is clear which one rules. This is such a case.

Comment: What is the medium you speak of? The slits? The screen?

Comment: You take the whole apparatus and dunk it in a water tank. Or just pressurize the air in the room.

Comment: I'm talking about in a vacuum where only slits, detection screen, electrons and randomly emitted photons are involved.

Comment: Yes. I know. But you wanted to know what the right property to use in analyzing the experiment is. It's wavelength.

Comment: What determines the wavelength if photons are not involved?

Comment: So back to my original question what determines the wavelength? In a vacuum, with slits, detection screen and electrons. There is no medium but a pattern with certain spacings forms. We know the dimensions of the experiment but what determined the wavelength and/or frequencies?

Comment: @BillAlsept:  Perhaps you should reread dmckee's answer.  Try searching the page for "de Broglie wavelength".

Comment: If by page you mean his answer I reread it and it speaks of a medium which my experiment does not have. As for the De Broglie wavelength again what physically determines it?

Comment: @Bill The answer in my post is "the de Broglie wavelength". Everything else is to explain why that is the correct answer. There is no dependence of the answer on your doing or not doing the experiment in a non-trivial medium. The medium is only mentioned to explain why wavelength is the right variable to concern yourself with.

Comment: I am not trying to be a pest but I am confused. My question was what determines the wavelength and your answer is the De Broglie wavelength? That makes no sense to me and I'm just asking shouldn't there be more to that answer? A wavelength is determined by another wavelength?

Comment: So the De Broglie wavelength is Planck's Constant divided by the momentum of the particle. With electrons we know the mass so basically it's the same as calculating the velocity. Which is what  I assumed and what Holger answered in the first comment. So from there I had additional questions in the second comment which was why I raised the question to begin with.